# Angular-ui-router Login required and user level

Tags: javascript, angularjs, firebase, angular-ui-router, angularfire

I have little problem with Angurafire with angular-ui-router.

I have this code for my login script, and it works

```js
.factory('Auth', function($firebaseAuth){
  var auth = $firebaseAuth();
  return auth;
 })

.controller('authCtrl', function(Auth, $state) {
  var authCtrl = this;

  authCtrl.user = {
    email : '',
    password  : ''
  };

  authCtrl.login = function (){
    Auth.$signInWithEmailAndPassword(authCtrl.user.email, authCtrl.user.password).then(function(auth){
      $state.go('home');
    }, function (error){
      $('#loginError').text('Helaas, uw gegevens kom niet overeen');
    });
  };
```

```
angular.module('myApp.cursustext', ['ui.router'])

.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider){
  $stateProvider.state('cursustext', {
   url: '/cursustext',
   templateUrl: 'views/cursustext/cursustext.html',
   controller: 'cursustextCtrl'
  })
});
```

How can I arrange that on some pages, you must be logged in?

***EXTRA***

In the database there is a userlevel at the user, how can I arrange that you need some special userlevel for a page (9 or something for Admin)

***UPDATE***

Somthing likes this:

```
.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider){
  $stateProvider.state('cursustext', {
   url: '/cursustext',
   templateUrl: 'views/cursustext/cursustext.html',
   controller: 'cursustextCtrl',
   loginstatus: true,
   userlevel: '5'
  })
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's say each user object retrieved from Firebase has some paramater user.level that is an integer and, the higher the integer, the higher the user's permissions. I would go about solving your problem as follows. 
(I am assuming you are making your single-page app the standard way with either components or templates+controllers for each page to which a user might try to navigate.)

I would inject your firebase service or some go-between for Firebase into each of your controllers for pages/components that need to check user-authorization level and, from there, check the user's auth level at the very start of the controller's initialization. Once the user's auth-level is known, check whether it is higher than the page's permission level and, if it isn't, reroute the user to a different page (perhaps a forbidden or home page) using the $window or $location.

i.e.

```
angular.module('MyApp').controller("adminPageController", function(FirebaseService, $location) {
    if (FirebaseSerice.user.level < 5) {
        $location.path('/homePage')
    }

    // ... rest of your code for your controller here
}
```

Comment: But, is this the easiest why? because know you must do this every page where you want it.
`$stateProvider.state('cursustext', {
   url: '/cursustext',
   templateUrl: 'views/cursustext/cursustext.html',
   controller: 'cursustextCtrl',
   userlevel: '5'
  })`
There is nothing in this way?
That it is always checked when you change path, before you get to the page. And one the same why with `loginstatus: true`?

Comment: I suppose you could add some resolve's to your routing config that might intercept and reroute.